# Linq to group by and split a datatable - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, group-by

I have a data table which I was to split as multiple datatables. The structure inside the datatable has three columns

**Company Name. Emp Name and Phone**
I want to split the whole datatable into multiple datatables each containing all the employees from one company. I hope I am making sense here with my question. I understood linq is the best way to go about doing this, but I have never used linq before and have completely no idea of how to go about doing this.
Can some one give me a lead on how to go about this? Some code example would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is the list of available companies static?  Why do you want to split it up into N datatables which you'll have to keep track of in another array or something anyway?  (And by `DataTable`, you mean the .NET object `System.Data.DataTable`, right?)

Comment: Are you talking about some form of database sharding? If so this should be kept transparent from your linq queries. Or are you trying to keep each company separate manually?

Comment: I think I didnt get through very clear. My exact requirement is that I want to generate an excel file for each company to send them. I assumed that splitting my datatable (System.Data.DataTable) into different datatables would help as I know how to generate excel files from datatables. Is there any other way to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your company names and data tables as dictionary using this:

```
Dim dict = dataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("CompanyName")).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) CopyToDataTable)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I did figure it out. I would just like to point out the reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions to get it for any other users who are looking for it. Thanks